# User storage not persisting

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

I am trying to keep a hold on values grabbed during the conversation and make it available on the next conversations on the flow using user storage. However I see empty user storage on my next intent. Can someone please advise?

```
  function askAccountNumber(agent){

      var number = agent.parameters.account_number;   

      let conv = agent.conv();      
      conv.user.storage.account_number = number;                  

      agent.add('Great, your account number is ' + tmp);      
      agent.add('Welcome to the Enacomm banking application. What would you like to do?')      
  }


function askService(agent){

    let conv = agent.conv();
    agent.add(JSON.stringify(conv.user.storage));    //THIS IS BLANK {}      

    var service_type = agent.parameters.service_type; 
    agent.add('Good! You asked for ' + service_type);    
  }
```

Comment: This seems to be an issue on the dialogflow-fulfillment library: https://github.com/dialogflow/dialogflow-fulfillment-nodejs/issues/196.
The repository seems pretty inactive for many months, so if I were you, I'll take a look at how to build an app with the Actions on Google library: https://github.com/actions-on-google/actions-on-google-nodejs/issues :)

Comment: Thanks @ThomasLombart . I changed the library as you suggested and it worked like a charm!!!

Comment: Glad it helped!

Answer (score 0):

This is an open issue on the dialogflow-fulfillment-nodejs library.

I changed my library from dialogflow-fulfillment-nodejs  to actions-on-google-nodejs and it worked like a charm.