# Setting Dialogflow Context using Actions Sdk

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

I'm currently experiencing issues with Google's user storage object. This used to work fine, but lately different actions and environments have stopped working due to the user storage not persisting past the first intent. When investigating the issue I ran into the a stackoverflow [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56237477/user-storage-not-persisting). It recommends to change from the Dialogflow SDK to the actionsOnGoogle SDK when you are having problems like this.

I've tried doing this, but when I change to the actions SDK I can no longer interact with the dialogflow context code.

[image]

Does changing to the actionSDK change anything about how the user storage works and if so, is it possible to migrate to the actionsSDK and keep using the dialogflow contexts?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, of course you can manage the "context" of the conversation in an SDK Action but no, it is not "just like" DialogFlow. Take a look at the "data" and "userStorage" members of the conversation object. The former is used to store data across turns of a single conversation. The latter is used to persist data across conversations with your Action.

Comment: Thanks for your response, your answer would allow me save key pieces of information for my conversation, but it doesn't allow me to control Dialogflow context. I've clarified my question a bit.